# Preventing a form from being submitted by spamming visitor

Tags: html, forms, form-submit, spam-prevention

I have a form that is being spammed. The website provider forces that form on a page that can't be deleted (a registration page), so I can't suppress that page or the form. I can however add Html to the page.

Adding javascript to disable the submit button won't work because spammer bots don't run javascript.

The website provider offers a captcha plugin for a price. (So now I'm wondering if the provider is spamming the site so I will buy the captcha!)

Is there any way to roll your own non-javascript captcha?

Answer so far: no! fuhgeddaboudit

Comment: `<input type="hidden"><input type="checkbox">`  try to use this, and if someone inputs the first input, then, it is a robot.

Comment: Anyone who uses the form is a robot! That I know, I just can't prevent the form from appearing on the site (provider imposes that).  I'm trying to prevent the form from being used at all.

Comment: How about using DOM event? look [this](https://blog.csdn.net/czh500/article/details/107845667)

Answer (score 1):

Most spam prevention is in the form processing script.

If you can't us JS on the front-end to stop spamming, then you need to work on the processing script.

One simple way to cut down some of the spam is to use a Honeypot field which is basically a hidden field that bot try to fill out anyway, and in the processing script you will say something like: if this field is filled out, then don't send the form, else, do send the form.

Comment: Thanks! I don't have access to the backend, so blocked for that. I thought it might be possible to inject broken html that would break the page. I will give that a try. Basically, I want to kill the whole page, if possible. (The provider does not let me remove it from the site.)

Comment: Nope; the site fixes any broken html. Looks like I am forced to buy their captcha!

Comment: Sounds like a bad deal indeed. I have never heard of any website providers forcing forms. Obviously, it's a selling point for them. Is there another provider you can use instead?